# Manter valor de elementos select ao clonar com jQuery e eliminar labels

Tags: html, jquery

#### Cenário teste

```js
function addReg(){

 var reg = $('#registro').clone().removeAttr('id');
 reg.children('label').remove();
 $('#formX').append(reg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 
 <div class="row">
  <form id="formX" method="get" action="kk.php">
   <div id="registro" class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
     <label for="origem">Origem</label>
     <select id="origem" class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="origem">
      <option selected>Selecione...</option>
      <option>Item 1</option>
      <option>Item 2</option>
      <option>Item 3</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
     <label for="destino">Destino</label>
     <select id="destino" class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="destino">
      <option selected>Selecione...</option>
      <option>Item 1</option>
      <option>Item 2</option>
      <option>Item 3</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
     <label for="item">Item</label>
     <select id="item" class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="item">
      <option selected>Selecione...</option>
      <option>Item 1</option>
      <option>Item 2</option>
      <option>Item 3</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
     <label for="hora">Hora</label>
     <input id="hora" type="time" class="form-control" name="hora">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
     <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="padding-top: 40px;">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="bf" value="bf" tabindex="-1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="bf"><b>BF</b></label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <button form="formX" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-3" tabindex="-1">Salvar</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="addReg()" tabindex="-1">+</button>
 </div>

</div>
```

---

#### Problemas

Quando faço o clone, ele não traz os valores dos elementos `select`.

Também, mantém os elementos `label`, claro, porque estou copiando tudo. Já tentei remover mas não consegui.

[image: add]

---

#### Dúvidas

- Como faço para manter o valor selecionado dos elementos `select`?
- Como faço para clonar sempre o "último clone"? (removo o id do anterior e adiciono no clonado?)
- Como faço para eliminar os elementos `label` (dos elementos do tipo `input`) para não duplicá-los?

Comment: Resumindo: você quer que, ao clonar, sejam utilizados os últimos valores selecionados e sem os labels?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss isso! rs

Comment: E o "BF", vai remover tb?

Comment: @Sam Não, o BF mantém!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você faz o `clone` no jQuery, o estado dos `select` não é clonado junto, então você precisará definir os valores conforme o último valor selecionado. Para tal, você pode sempre clonar o último item da sua lista; após clonar você pode percorrer todos os `select` e definir os valores conforme o item clonado. Por fim, você oculta todas as `label` do novo elemento e adiciona-o na DOM.

```
function addReg() {
  // Pega o último item da lista
  const template = $('#formX > div').last();

  // Faz o clone
  const novo = template.clone();

  // Define os valores dos select conforme o item clonado
  $(template).find('select').each(function(i) {
    $(novo).find("select").eq(i).val($(this).val());
  });

  // Oculta os labels
  novo.find('label').hide();

  // Mantém os labels dos checkbox
  novo.find('input[type=checkbox] + label').show();

  // Adiciona o elemento na DOM
  $('#formX').append(novo);
}
```

Veja funcionando:

```js
function addReg() {
  const template = $('#formX > div').last();
  const novo = template.clone();
  
  $(template).find('select').each(function(i) {
    $(novo).find("select").eq(i).val($(this).val());
  });
  
  novo.find('label').hide();
  novo.find('input[type=checkbox] + label').show();
  
  $('#formX').append(novo);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form id="formX" method="get" action="kk.php">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group mr-2">
          <label for="origem">Origem</label>
          <select class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="origem">
            <option selected>Selecione...</option>
            <option>Item 1</option>
            <option>Item 2</option>
            <option>Item 3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mr-2">
          <label for="destino">Destino</label>
          <select class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="destino">
            <option selected>Selecione...</option>
            <option>Item 1</option>
            <option>Item 2</option>
            <option>Item 3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mr-2">
          <label for="item">Item</label>
          <select class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="item">
            <option selected>Selecione...</option>
            <option>Item 1</option>
            <option>Item 2</option>
            <option>Item 3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mr-2">
          <label for="hora">Hora</label>
          <input type="time" class="form-control" name="hora">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="padding-top: 40px;">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="bf" tabindex="-1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="bf"><b>BF</b></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button form="formX" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-3" tabindex="-1">Salvar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="addReg()" tabindex="-1">+</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Fiz uma nova função Jquery para fazer o clone, assim você pode usar em outros lugares no futuro, e pode acontecer de ter algum problema parecido em outro elemento, caso isso aconteça você pode alterar somente esta função para criar um clone personalizado.

```js
//Criei uma nova função para o Jquery, assim ela pode ser reaproveitada em outros momentos,
//e caso tenha problema ao clonar outro elemento, e só alterar esta função
$.fn.newClone = function(){ 
    var novo = this.clone();
    var self = this;
    novo.find('select').each(function(i) {
      $(this).val($(self).find("select").eq(i).val());
    });
    return novo;
}

function addReg(){
  var novo = $('#formX > div').last().newClone();//Utilizo o novo cloe
  novo.find('label').not('.form-check-label').remove();//E utilizo o "not" para não aplicar a remoção do label para o checkbox
  $('#formX').append(novo);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 
 <div class="row">
  <form id="formX" method="get" action="kk.php">
   <div id="registro" class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
     <label for="origem">Origem</label>
     <select id="origem" class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="origem">
      <option selected>Selecione...</option>
      <option>Item 1</option>
      <option>Item 2</option>
      <option>Item 3</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
     <label for="destino">Destino</label>
     <select id="destino" class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="destino">
      <option selected>Selecione...</option>
      <option>Item 1</option>
      <option>Item 2</option>
      <option>Item 3</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
     <label for="item">Item</label>
     <select id="item" class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="item">
      <option selected>Selecione...</option>
      <option>Item 1</option>
      <option>Item 2</option>
      <option>Item 3</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
     <label for="hora">Hora</label>
     <input id="hora" type="time" class="form-control" name="hora">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
     <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="padding-top: 40px;">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="bf" value="bf" tabindex="-1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="bf"><b>BF</b></label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <button form="formX" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-3" tabindex="-1">Salvar</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="addReg()" tabindex="-1">+</button>
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tente realizar fazer dessa forma:

```js
function addReg(){
  var ultimo = $('#formX > div').last();
  var novo = ultimo.clone();
  
  //Seleciona os valores do ultimo clone e seta no novo clone
  novo.find("#origem").val(ultimo.find("#origem").val());
  novo.find("#destino").val(ultimo.find("#destino").val());
  novo.find("#item").val(ultimo.find("#item").val());  
  
  //Remove todos os labels do clone menos o BF
  novo.find('label').not('.form-check-label').remove();
    
  $('#formX').append(novo);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 
 <div class="row">
  <form id="formX" method="get" action="kk.php">
   <div id="registro" class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
     <label for="origem">Origem</label>
     <select id="origem" class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="origem">
      <option selected>Selecione...</option>
      <option>Item 1</option>
      <option>Item 2</option>
      <option>Item 3</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
     <label for="destino">Destino</label>
     <select id="destino" class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="destino">
      <option selected>Selecione...</option>
      <option>Item 1</option>
      <option>Item 2</option>
      <option>Item 3</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
     <label for="item">Item</label>
     <select id="item" class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="item">
      <option selected>Selecione...</option>
      <option>Item 1</option>
      <option>Item 2</option>
      <option>Item 3</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
     <label for="hora">Hora</label>
     <input id="hora" type="time" class="form-control" name="hora">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
     <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="padding-top: 40px;">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="bf" value="bf" tabindex="-1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="bf"><b>BF</b></label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <button form="formX" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-3" tabindex="-1">Salvar</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="addReg()" tabindex="-1">+</button>
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Albertt, não está clonando o registro anterior, ele clona somente o primeiro...

Comment: Correção aplicada!

Answer (score 1):

Ao clonar o elemento, irá repetir as id's dos elementos filhos. Esta solução irá remover todos os id's repetidos e manter o clique no `label` do checkbox **BF** criando um `id` e um `for` único para cada um, mantendo a sua funcionalidade:

> Outro detalhe que notei é alterar os `name`'s para array caso for ter
>   que enviar pro backend, adicionando os colchetes `[]`. Ex.:
>   `name="origem[]`, `name="destino[]"` etc...

**Solução:**

```js
function addReg(){
   
   //conta a quantidade de linhas
   var novo_id = $("#formX > .form-row").length;
   
   // seleciona a última linha
   var reg = $("#formX .form-row:last");

   // clona o elemento e remove o id
   var clone = reg.clone().removeAttr("id");

   // remove os ids dos selects
   clone.find("select").removeAttr("id");

   // atribui novo id ao checkbox do "BF"
   clone.find("input:last").attr("id", "bf"+novo_id);

   // atribui novo "for" ao label do "BF"
   clone.find("label:last").attr("for", "bf"+novo_id);

   // remove todos os labels, menos o último, que é o "BF"
   clone.find("label:not(:last)").remove();
   
   // percorre todos os últimos elementos de cada .form-group
   // da última linha
   $("#formX .form-row:last .form-group *:last-child").each(function(){
      clone
      .find("[name='"+ $(this).attr("name") +"']") // busca o elemento com o mesmo name
      .val( $(this).val() ); // altera o respectivo elemento no clone
   });

   // insere o clone no form
   $("#formX").append(clone);
      
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
 
 <div class="row">
  <form id="formX" method="get" action="kk.php">
   <div id="registro" class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
     <label for="origem">Origem</label>
     <select id="origem" class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="origem[]">
      <option selected>Selecione...</option>
      <option>Item 1</option>
      <option>Item 2</option>
      <option>Item 3</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
     <label for="destino">Destino</label>
     <select id="destino" class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="destino[]">
      <option selected>Selecione...</option>
      <option>Item 1</option>
      <option>Item 2</option>
      <option>Item 3</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
     <label for="item">Item</label>
     <select id="item" class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="item[]">
      <option selected>Selecione...</option>
      <option>Item 1</option>
      <option>Item 2</option>
      <option>Item 3</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
     <label for="hora">Hora</label>
     <input id="hora" type="time" class="form-control" name="hora[]">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
     <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="padding-top: 40px;">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="bf" value="bf" tabindex="-1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="bf"><b>BF</b></label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <button form="formX" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-3" tabindex="-1">Salvar</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="addReg()" tabindex="-1">+</button>
 </div>

</div>
```